# OS X CPAN Perl module installation issue

Tags: perl, installation, perl-module, cpan, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to install Perl module `MediaWiki::API` using CPAN on OS X:

```
sudo cpan MediaWiki::API                                                        Password:
Reading '/Users/qazwsx/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 13 Jul 2015 20:53:32 GMT
Running install for module 'MediaWiki::API'
Running make for E/EX/EXOBUZZ/MediaWiki-API-0.40.tar.gz
Checksum for /Users/qazwsx/.cpan/sources/authors/id/E/EX/EXOBUZZ/MediaWiki-API-0.40.tar.gz ok
sh: /opt/local/bin/gzip: No such file or directory
Package seems to come without Makefile.PL.
  (The test -f "/Users/qazwsx/.cpan/build/EXOBUZZ-iwzBiH/Makefile.PL" returned false.)
  Writing one on our own (setting NAME to MediaWikiAPI)

  CPAN.pm: Building E/EX/EXOBUZZ/MediaWiki-API-0.40.tar.gz

Writing Makefile for MediaWikiAPI
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  EXOBUZZ/MediaWiki-API-0.40.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
No tests defined for MediaWikiAPI extension.
  EXOBUZZ/MediaWiki-API-0.40.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install
Appending installation info to /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level/perllocal.pod
  EXOBUZZ/MediaWiki-API-0.40.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
```

This is a step of installing Git-Mediawiki (see https://github.com/moy/Git-Mediawiki/wiki/User-manual).  However, after all the installation steps, the first git command reports that `MediaWiki::API` module isn't available:

```
git pull
Can't locate MediaWiki/API.pm in @INC (you may need to install the MediaWiki::API module) (@INC contains: /Users/qazwsx/WorkSpace-X4430/git/perl /Users/qazwsx/WorkSpace-X4430/git/contrib/mw-to-git /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.4.1/libexec/git-core/git-remote-mediawiki line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.4.1/libexec/git-core/git-remote-mediawiki line 15.
```

I wonder if my installation method for the Perl module is correct. One thing strikes out as odd is the error

```
sh: /opt/local/bin/gzip: No such file or directory
```

I use Homebrew with standard paths, so the gzip binary is at /usr/local/bin/gzip.  But I don't know if or where to fix it. It appears to be some search paths issue but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I used `cpanp` to install MediaWiki::API 0.40 on Mac OS X 10.10.4 without a problem.  But I also used my own build of Perl 5.22.0 rather than the system-provided Perl (I don't tamper with the system's Perl as a matter of personal policy).

Comment: The reference to `/opt/local` looks like you have some remains of a MacPorts installation on your system. It's reasonably likely that that could be what's messing things up for you.

Comment: I've verified that `/opt/local` does not exist on my computer.

Comment: As you are running under `sudo`, it might be an idea to check the PATH that applies in that environment with `sudo env`.

Comment: @ JonathanLeffler Can you describe how to do that as an answer?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I checked with `sudo env` and verified that `opt/local/bin` is NOT in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be something wrong with your `~/.cpan`, the configuration for CPAN. You can try

```
# Re-install cpan
brew doctor
brew update
brew install cpan

# Remove or back up ~/.cpan
mv ~/.cpan ~/.cpan.bak

# Re-initialize ~/.cpan
cpan config

# Try installing the Perl module again
sudo cpan install MediaWiki::API
```

Comment: Is there a cpan Formula?

Comment: Probably so at that time, but as I just verified now, it is `cpanminus` as of 2023-1.